# Как выполнить UPDATE нескольких значений по данным из другой таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 2 таблицы, мне нужно увеличить значение `price` стобца `s_variants` на 10% где `brand_id = 84` и `price < 1000`.
Пробывал сделать через `JOIN` он не работает, попробывал через подзапрос

```
UPDATE `s_variants` 
SET `s_variants`.`price`= `s_variants`.`price` * 1.1  
WHERE `s_variants`.`price` < 1000 
AND `s_variants`.`product_id` = 
(SELECT `s_products`.`id` FROM `s_products` WHERE `s_products`.`brand_id` = 84)
```

Но, получаю ошибку, что подзапрос возвращает несколько вариантов.
Как правильно составить запрос, что бы выполнить задачу?

таблица **s_products**

```
|  id  |  brand_id  |
 -------------------
|   1  |     21     |
|   5  |     84     |
|  235 |     84     |
```

таблица **s_variants**

```
|  id  | product_id |  price |
 ----------------------------
|  38  |     1      |   545  |
|  25  |     5      |   158  |
|  35  |     235    |   999  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Абсолютно правильная ошибка, результат выполнения подзапроса - множество, значит знак равенства не подойдет. Вам нужно использовать in

```
UPDATE `s_variants` 
SET `s_variants`.`price`= `s_variants`.`price` * 1.1  
WHERE `s_variants`.`price` < 1000 
AND `s_variants`.`product_id` IN 
(SELECT `s_products`.`id` FROM `s_products` WHERE `s_products`.`brand_id` = 84)
```

[пример на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6587d/5)